Tuple matching using SQLAlchemy
Let's say I have a db of Customers. I want to fetch data and filter rows by exact pairs.
I want to do the following using sqlalchemy:
SELECT first_name, age
FROM Customers
WHERE (first_name, age) in (('John', '31'),('Robert', '22'));

I know I can do this:

SELECT first_name, age
FROM Customers
WHERE first_name in ('John', 'Robert') and age in ('31','22');

like this:
with get_mariadb_session() as session:
    query = select(
        Customers.name, 
        Customers.age, 
        Customers.email
    ).select_from(
        Customers
    ).where(
        and_(Customers.name.in_(names), Customers.age.in_(ages))
    )
    res = session.execute(query)

But this might return a result set with a record ('John','22') too.
Is it possible to do tuple matching in sqlalchemy?

select(Customers.name, Customers.age, Customers.email).select_from(Customers).where(tuple_(Customers.name, Customers.age).in_([("John", "31"), ("Robert", "22")])). tuple_ is from sqlalchemy import tuple_

You can See the docs for using tuple in query here:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/operators.html#tuple-in-expressions

@python_user Ah I looked for something like tuple_ in sqlalchemy.sql.operators didn't think it would be inside sqlalchemy itself.

You can do this by wrapping the LHS with sqlalchemy.tuple_
import sqlalchemy as sa
...
with Session() as s:
    q = (
        sa.select(Customer.name, Customer.age)
        .select_from(Customer)
        .where(
            sa.tuple_(Customer.name, Customer.age).in_(
                [("John", "31"), ("Robert", "22")]
            )
        )
    )
    for customer in s.execute(q):
        print(f"{customer.name = } {customer.age = }")



beat you to it :p

Ah!  I'm on lots of trains today, so composing answers offline and answering when I get on a network, so I didn't see the comments @python_user

@python_user also it turned out that my laptop didn't have mariadb installed, which slowed me down a little ;-)
